# nodeJS/node-7z : how to write a stream on the hard drive

Tags: node.js

I am a very beginner in nodeJS, so I can't succeed with the examples of the 'node-7z' package that I find on rpm repository.

In fact I just want to make a .7z file from a Access database (.accdb file), but I can't find to write the node-7z stream on my hard drive.

So I use this code, can you help, just to write it ?

thank you very much

```
var Seven = require("node-7z")

let fileentree = 'D:/Users/F/Dev/NodeJS/Sauvegardes7Zip_NodeJS/Database.accdb'
let filecompressee = 'D:/Users/F/Dev/NodeJS/Sauvegardes7Zip_NodeJS/Archive.7z'
let path7zip = 'C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe'

// myStream is an Readable stream
const myStream = Seven.add(filecompressee,fileentree, {
    $bin: path7zip,
    y: true,
    ssw: true
 });
```

Comment: And the problem is? Any error? You can add `myStream.on('error', console.log)` to see if there was an error.

Comment: I try to catch the error, but nothing will be display.

When I try bad arguments, they appear in the console, so the "myStream.on('error', console.log)" is working but myStream don't generate error



var Seven = require("node-7z")

let fileentree = 'D:/Users/F/Dev/NodeJS/Sauvegardes7Zip_NodeJS/Database.accdb'
let filecompressee = 'D:/Users/F/Dev/NodeJS/Sauvegardes7Zip_NodeJS/Archive.7z'
let path7zip = 'C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe'

const myStream = Seven.add(filecompressee,fileentree, {
  $bin: path7zip,
  y: true,
  ssw: true
})

myStream.on('error', console.log)

Comment: What are you trying to say? Do you see any error?

Comment: I don't have any error when I try the code I posted on the top of this topic. I try to launch it on another computer, and it works. it is very strange, my problem come from computer configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Use [fs.createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options):

```
const fs = require('fs');

const myStream = ...

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('path/to/my/disk/file');

myStream.pipe(writeStream);
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I try it but the generate file with createWriteStream is empty. Maybe then const myStream = Seven.add( ... doesn't work